# How to switch turns in a game of tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a game of tic tac toe for a small school project and I'm stuck in how I can change the players. Here's what the code looks like:

```
function clickTurn(square) {
    if (typeof playBoard[square.target.id] == 'number') {
        turn(square.target.id, player1);
        turn(square.target.id, player2);
    }
}

function turn(squareId, player) {
    playBoard[squareId] = player;
    document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = player;
    console.log(playBoard);
    let gameWon = checkWin(playBoard, player)
    if (gameWon) {
        gameOver(gameWon)
    }
}
```

I know that calling the turn function twice in a row won't work, how can i make it so that after calling it with player1, I can call it again with player2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the current player and swap them after the move

```
var player1 = 'O';
var player2 = 'X';
var currentPlayer = player1;

function clickTurn(square) {
    if (typeof playBoard[square.target.id] == 'number') {
        turn(square.target.id, currentPlayer);
    
        if (currentPlayer === player1) {
            currentPlayer = player2;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = player1;
        }
        // currentPlayer = currentPlayer === player1 ? player2 : player1;
    }

}
```